# Save when new record and update when edit on data occurs

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-update

I have my code for save button and update button but is there a way I can combine the two
commands in one button?

For example When I click 'SAVE/UPDATE Button' it will save on the database if it is a new record and it will rather update if the system found that there is already record on the database and save the edited data's

CODE FOR SAVE BUTTON

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"
    Try
        Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand
        sqlconn.Open()
        myCommand = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_Category,OE_SubCategory,OE_ID,OE_Name,OE_User,OE_Brand,OE_Model,OE_Specs,OE_SerialNo,OE_PropertyNo,OE_MacAddress,OE_Static_IP,OE_Vendor,OE_PurchaseDate,OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear,OE_WarrantyStatus,OE_Status,OE_Dept_Code,OE_Location_Code,OE_Remarks) VALUES('" & cmbCategory.Text & "','" & cmbSubCategory.Text & "','" & txtOEID.Text & "','" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtUser.Text & "','" & cmbBrand.Text & "','" & cmbModel.Text & "','" & txtSpecs.Text & "','" & txtSerialNo.Text & "','" & txtPropertyNo.Text & "','" & txtMacAddress.Text & "','" & txtStaticIp.Text & "','" & txtVendor.Text & "','" & txtPurchaseDate.Text & "','" & txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text & "', '" & txtWarrantyStatus.Text & "','" & txtStatus.Text & "','" & cmbDeptCode.Text & "','" & cmbLocationCode.Text & "','" & txtRemarks.Text & "')", sqlconn)
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Office Equipment Profile Successfully Added")
        sqlconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

CODE FOR UPDATE BUTTON (NOTE: but still my update button has some error still trying to fix)

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim myCommand As New SqlCommand


    Try

        'update command
        sqlconn.Open()

        myCommand = New SqlCommand("UPDATE tblOfficeEquipmentProfile SET OE_Category = '" & cmbCategory.Text & "',OE_SubCategory = '" & cmbSubCategory.Text & "', OE_Name = '" & txtName.Text & "', OE_User = '" & txtUser.Text & "', OE_Brand = '" & cmbBrand.Text & "', OE_Model = '" & cmbModel.Text & "', OE_Specs = '" & txtSpecs.Text & "', OE_SerialNo = '" & txtSerialNo.Text & "', OE_PropertyNo = '" & txtPropertyNo.Text & "', OE_MacAddress = '" & txtMacAddress.Text & "', OE_Static_IP = '" & txtStaticIp.Text & "', OE_Vendor = '" & txtVendor.Text & "', OE_PurchaseDate = '" & txtPurchaseDate.Text & "', OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear = '" & txtWarrantyInclusiveYear.Text & "', OE_WarrantyStatus = '" & txtWarrantyStatus.Text & "', OE_Status = '" & txtStatus.Text & "', OE_Dept_Code = '" & cmbDeptCode.Text & "', OE_Location_Code = '" & cmbLocationCode.Text & "', OE_Remarks ='" & txtRemarks.Text & "' WHERE OE_ID ='" & txtOEID.Text & "'", sqlconn)
        Dim iCnt As Integer = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MessageBox.Show("Office Equipment Profile Successfully Updated  " & iCnt & "  Records")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an enum that contains the state:

```
 Enum DataState
      Editing
      Adding
      None
 End Enum
```

Then set a class-level variable:

```
 private mDataState as DataState
```

Then set this according to whether you are adding or editing a record, then in the Save_Click subroutine, use an If-Then.

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored procedure that checks to see if the record exists.  If it does, update it.  Otherwise, insert it.

Call this stored procedure from your vb.net code.  Also, change your .net code so that it sends query parameters to your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a perennial favorite question here on SO: how to update an existing row or else insert it?  And the answers are perennially wrong.

The standard SQL to do this does not have an `if` statement.  The standard way is to insert the row subject to the constraint that it does not exist, and then update it:

```
insert into T values (...)
where not exists (
  select 1 from T as t 
  where T.key = t.key
)
```

optionally check the rowcount and only update if it's 0

```
update T set ... 
where T.key = value
```

If you don't check the rowcount from `insert`, the `update` is redundant.

It's better to put all that in a stored procedure but, even if you don't, you should be able to put both statements in one prepared statement, and attach that to one button in your GUI.